# Aframe: change att to update

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have written a component. At begin, the movement of two objects(drawer and infusioncutlery) is synchronous. After the click on infusioncutlery should the movement of drawer independent. The infusioncutlery doesn't move anymore. The result of the code now is: after the click on infusioncutlery, the code under the condition "if(data.moveWithInfusion===true)" still, run. And the code under "if(data.moveWithInfusion===false)" run also. I can't find the reason. Does somebody know the reason? Thanks!
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/skill-lab

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('drawerwithinfusioncutlery',{

  schema: {
    open : {default: '1.8 0 0.1'},
    close : {default: '0 0 0.1'},
    dur : {default: 300},
    moveWithInfusion :{default: true},
  },

  update: function (){
    var data= this.data;
    var el=this.el;
    var closed=true;
    var infusion=document.querySelector("#infusioninpack");

    el.addEventListener("click",function(){
      if(data.moveWithInfusion===true){
        alert("true");
        if(closed === true){
          open(el, data.close, data.open, data.dur);
          open(infusion, '1.24 4.439 1.555', '3.04 4.439 1.555', data.dur);
          closed=false;
        }else if(closed===false){
          open(el, data.open, data.close, data.dur);
          open(infusion, '3.04 4.439 1.555', '1.24 4.439 1.555', data.dur);
          closed=true;
        }   
      }else if(data.moveWithInfusion===false){
        alert("false");
        if(closed === true){
          open(el, data.close, data.open, data.dur);
          closed=false;
        }else if(closed===false){
          open(el, data.open, data.close, data.dur);
          closed=true;
        }   
      }  
    });

    infusion.addEventListener("click",function(){
      el.setAttribute('drawerwithinfusioncutlery', {moveWithInfusion: 'false'})
    });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the event listeners should be in the `init` function, to prevent duplicating them.

So I've thrown out the 'click' listener to the `init` function. And I've added the 'closed' variable in the `init`, as it's used in the listener's labda function, and now it seems to be working properly:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gigantic-toucan?path=public/js/drawerwithinfusioncutlery.js:26:25

Comment: Thank you very much. My goal is moving the drawer without the move of infusionscutlery after one click on infusioncutlery.  I solve the problem with your suggestion. Thanks.